# Does Docx4j enterprise edition update the Table of contents of Word .docx file with java?

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using docx4j open source edition for manipulating word .docx document, But I am not able to update Table of contents.
docx4j open source does not support updating TOC.

Can Docx4j Enterprise edition support updating Table of Contents programmatically 
using java.

Answer (score 0):

For soon to be released version 3.3.0, the ToC update code has been migrated to the open source edition: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/VERSION_3_3_0/src/main/java/org/docx4j/toc

For best results page numbering in the ToC, use of PlutextDocumentServices is recommended. See further [TocGenerator.java#L519](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_3_3_0/src/main/java/org/docx4j/toc/TocGenerator.java#L519)

Comment: can you tell me estimated time, when it will be migrate ?